# I have created a user array, how could I remove name’s spacing in the user array using for loop?

Tags: arrays, space

Following is an example with only three users

const users = [
{
name: "Alan Brown",
initial: "AB”,
},
{
name: "Judy White",
initial: "JW"
},
{
name: "Bruce Lee",
initial: "bl"
}
]

Thank you so much for helping out!

Comment: You need only to remove space at name field? Do you mean like this:  const users = [ { name: "AlanBrown", initial: "AB”, }, { name: "JudyWhite", initial: "JW" }, { name: "BruceLee", initial: "bl" } ]

Comment: you can have a look of ```array.map()``` and ```string.replace()```

Comment: Is there any method/ function to just get the name out of the user array and then remove the name’s spacing ?

Comment: Which programming language is being used here?

Answer (score 0):

```
const users = [ { name: "Alan Brown", initial: "AB", }, { name: "Judy White", initial: "JW" }, { name: "Bruce Lee", initial: "bl" } ]


users.forEach(({ name }) => console.log(`${name}`));
```

> See here first error was with initial: "AB”, you have to write it as initial: "AB",

then here is the snippet of its working[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0RAY.png Here is the working

Comment: How about if I want to write something like this: 
      export default async function createUsers() {
               for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
               const user = users[i]
  }
};    How should I continue? TQ